# Что делать если нет переменной до загрузки сайта, но в коде есть цикл с той переменной?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код, и при загрузке страницы, нет еще такого элемента в html.
Только добавляется он если я нажму на кнопку. Как лучше всего решить такую проблему будет?

```
сonst exitMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.exit');

exitMenu.forEach(e => {
   e.addEventListener('click', () => {
      pupMenu.classList.add('hide');
      pupMenu.children[0].classList.remove('show-pub');
   })
});



openPub.forEach(e => {
   e.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      let htmlPubMenu;
      if (e.classList.contains('contact-pup')) {
         htmlPubMenu = `<div class="contact-menu d-flex">
         <div class="exit">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
         </div>

         <div class="left-side">
            <h3 class="contact-menu__title">LET'S TALK!</h3>
            <h2 class="contact-menu__sup-title">CALL ME OR SEND ME A REQUEST</h2>
            <div class="contact-menu__contact-person">
               <div class="contact-menu__phone-text">
                  <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> +380986404004
               </div>
               <div class="contact-menu__email-text">
                  <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> gapachilomaxim@gmail.com
               </div>
            </div>
            <form action="POST">
               <label for="email">
                  Adress e-mail
               </label>
               <input class="contact-menu__email" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Adress e-mail">

               <label for="text">
                  Request
               </label>
               <textarea class="contact-menu__request" name="text" id="text"
                  placeholder="Type your request..."></textarea>

               <div class="contact-menu__wrap-btn">
                  <button class="contact-menu__send" type="submit">SEND</button>
               </div>

            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="rigth-side">
            <div class="contact-menu__wrap-img">
               <img class="contact-menu__img" src="img/request.png" alt="request">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>`
      }
      pupMenu.innerHTML = htmlPubMenu;
      open()
   })
})
```

Comment: Выполнять все действия при добавлении элемента в html, т.е. видимо при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Но мне не надо все действия, так как та переменная , и есть кнопки что надо оброботать через цикл)

Comment: Значит перенесите в действие выполняемое по кнопке только все что связано с элементом который появляется

Comment: Если сonst exitMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.exit'); выбирает более одного элемента и не все из которых в новом блоке то оставьте его в покое и добавьте другой класс и аналогичное навешивание события уже после присвоения innerHTML (возможно стоит действия вынести в функцию что бы не дублировать код)

Comment: Я что то не понял все равно) , Мне надо создать addEventListener окремо но не получится потому что нет еще такого элемента при загрузке страницы, а после загрузки страницы будет в консоли ошибка - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null  потому что нет еще такого элемента

Comment: поместите addEventListener после pupMenu.innerHTML = htmlPubMenu;

Comment: @Mike а что можно всунуть в событие клику другой обработчик, и будет работать он?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как записать addEventListener если нет еще кнопки при загрузки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226612/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-addeventlistener-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Вызов функции addEventListener навешивает обработчик события и не важно в какой момент эта функция вызвана. Хоть через полчаса после загрузки страницы и появления элемента, по какому нибудь таймеру. Эти полчаса на события он реагировать не будет, а как только addEventListener вызвали то начнет