# Как записать addEventListener если нет еще кнопки при загрузки?

Tags: javascript

Вот у меня допустим разных три `addEventListener` на клик, но еще нет селекторов после загрузки сайта. Они появляются в определенный момент, и при загрузке страницы в консоли выдает Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, потому что нет селектора такой переменной еще. Как можно исправить такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот некоторые возможные решения:

1. Подключить скрипт внизу страницы, а не вверху. Тогда он сработает, когда уже есть все элементы.
2. Использовать [делегирование](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation) событий. То есть добавить обработчик на родительский элемент, и уже там проверять какой элемент был нажат. Это если родительский элемент существует. По крайне мере body есть всегда, но советую выбрать более близкий родитель, желательно непосредственный.
3. Проверять наличие элементов интервалом. Например раз в 200 миллисекунд (число на ваш вкус). Потом когда элементы обнаружены, сделать с ними дело, и убрать интервал. Интервал ничего ощутимо не ухудшит, однако обычно считается что так делать не следует.
4. Использовать событие [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) или если используете jQuery - метод [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).
5. Если элементы загружаются и вставляются в документ отдельно, то добавлять к ним обработчики событий можно в момент их вставки.

Comment: Ну тут только мне подходит e.target но все равно он не очень подходит хорошо, разметку html добавляю только через js , тому и не подходит подключить js в конце или другие способи. А в разметки есть  
<div class="exit">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
   </div>
и если поставить таргет на класс exit то при клике на тег i  не будет работать событие, мне надо на полный div поставить, как то можно с e.target поставиьт на весь див все что внутри там?

Comment: @MaksymGapachilo Если разметка вставляется скриптом, то можно просто после вставки найти нужный элемент и повесить на него слушатель без делегирования (без `e.target`). Также можно html не просто вставлять как `.innerHTML = "<div>....."`, а сначала превратить в элементы и навешать на них обработчики, и уже элементы вставлять через `parent.appendChild( elements )`